# How to Read a Esc key stroke with other keys in If-Else statement

Tags: c++, conio

I've tried everything i know to get it work right but i don't know how to make this program to
get terminated when escape key get pressed any help i know i can use getch or getchar to get the key stroke of esc key but i also want it to be working with my other inputs too...

I'm a beginner. Any ideas? How it can be done with this program?

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#include <conio.h>

using namespace std;

class Node {
public:
        int roll;
        string Name;
        string address;
        int contact;
        string email;
        Node* next;
};

Node* head = new Node();

bool check(int x)
{
        if (head == NULL)
                return false;

        Node* t = new Node;
        t = head;

        while (t != NULL) {
                if (t->roll == x)
                        return true;
                t = t->next;
        }

        return false;
}

void Insert_Record(int roll, string Name,
                   string address, int contact, string email)
{
        if (check(roll)) {
                cout << "Student with this "
                     << "record Already Exists\n";
                return;
        }
        Node* t = new Node();
        t->roll = roll;
        t->Name = Name;
        t->address = address;
        t->contact = contact;
        t->email = email;
        t->next = NULL;

        if (head == NULL|| (head->roll >= t->roll)) {
                t->next = head;
                head = t;
        }

        else {
                Node* c = head;
                while (c->next != NULL
                        && c->next->roll < t->roll) {
                        c = c->next;
                }
                t->next = c->next;
                c->next = t;
        }

        cout << "Record Inserted "
                << "Successfully\n";
}

void Search_Record(int roll)
{
        if (!head) {
                cout << "No such Record "
                        << "Avialable\n";
                return;
        }

        else {
                Node* p = head;
                while (p) {
                        if (p->roll == roll) {
                                cout << "Roll Nmuber\t"
                                        << p->roll << endl;
                                cout << "Name\t\t"
                                        << p->Name << endl;
                                cout << "Address\t"
                                        << p->address << endl;
                                cout << "Contact\t\t"
                                        << p->contact << endl;
                                cout << "Email\t\t"
                                        << p->email << endl;
                                return;
                        }
                        p = p->next;
                }

                if (p == NULL)
                        cout << "No such Record "
                             << "Avialable\n";
        }
}

int Delete_Record(int roll)
{
        Node* t = head;
        Node* p = NULL;

        // Deletion at Begin
        if (t != NULL && t->roll == roll) {
                head = t->next;
                delete t;

                cout << "Record Deleted "
                        << "Successfully\n";
                return 0;
        }

        // Deletion Other than Begin
        while (t != NULL && t->roll != roll) {
                p = t;
                t = t->next;
        }

        if (t == NULL) {
                cout << "Record does not Exist\n";
                return -1;
                p->next = t->next;

                delete t;
                cout << "Record Deleted "
                     << "Successfully\n";

                return 0;
        }
}

void Show_Record()
{
        Node* p = head;
        if (p == NULL) {
                cout << "No Record "
                        << "Available\n";
        }
        else {
                cout << "Roll-No\tName\tAddress\tContact\tEmail \n";

                while (p != NULL) {
                        cout<<""<< p->roll <<"\t\t"<< p->Name << "\t\t"<< p->address << "\t\t"<< p->contact << "\t\t"<< p->email << endl;
                        p = p->next;
                }
        }
}

int main()
{
        head = NULL;
        string Name, address, email;
        int Roll, contact;

        while (true) {
                cout << "\n\t\tWelcome "
                                "\n\n\tPress\n\t1 to Store New Data\n\t2 To Display the Record\n\t4 To delete a Data\n\t5 Press Escape Key to Exit\n";
                cout << "\nEnter your Choice\n";

                int Choice;
                
                cin>>Choice;
                if (Choice == 1) {
                        cout << "Enter Roll Number of Student\n";
                        cin >> Roll;
                        cout << "Enter Name of Student\n";
                        cin >> Name;
                        cout << "Enter The Address of Student \n";
                        cin >> address;
                        cout << "Enter  Contact of Student\n";
                        cin >> contact;
                        cout<< "Enter Email Address of the Student\n";
                        cin>> email;
                        Insert_Record(Roll, Name, address, contact, email);
                }
                else if (Choice == 2) {
                        cout << "Enter Roll Number of Student whose "
                                        "record you want to Search\n";
                        cin >> Roll;
                        Search_Record(Roll);
                }
                else if (Choice == 3) {
                        cout << "Enter Roll Number of Student whose "
                                        "record is to be deleted\n";
                        cin >> Roll;
                        Delete_Record(Roll);
                }
                else if (Choice == 0) {
                        exit (0);
                }
                else {
                        cout << "Invalid Choice "
                                << "Try Again\n";
                }
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Comment: `std::cin`, used like this, will read one character from the input buffer. So, if the user types "<ESC><ENTER>" you should be able to catch this by checking for character value 27. If you want to detect _key presses_ directly, then use something like `kbhit`. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11987717/c-cin-keypress-event).

Answer (score 0):

As you are already using conio.h, this answer probably has all you need.
[how to detect the ESC key in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34209854/how-to-detect-the-esc-key-in-c)

Be aware that conio/_getch may well "steal" characters from the cin stream, so you might be simpler to remove cin, and only use _getch/_kbhit().

EDIT: in response to comment

There are few design decisions to be made here. By trying to bypass the limitations of the C++ model, you are entering the slightly obscure world of OS-Specific character codes. You will need to decide how many of these codes you want to support.
This really comes down to usability.
Do you want to support backspace/delete?
How about cursor keys?
How about tabs?
The table [here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/wide/iswspace) gives some sort of idea how complex this can get. However, maybe you don't need it that complex?
It's up to you.

If it were me, I'd aim to store a line at a time, in a std::string. On a newline character, make a [std::istringstream](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/stringstream-in-cplusplus#:%7E:text=Here%20we%20will%20see%20the%20string%20stream%20in,string%20object%20whose%20content%20is%20present%20in%20stream) to do complex input parsing.

Like all user-interface design, it's fun to play with, but is often a lot of work to make perfect.

Comment: but i dont know how im going to use _getch or _kbhit() in asking user's choices at the same time.